# 2D terrain generation

Tags: algorithm, generator, terrain

How is the terrain in games like "Moon buggy", "Route 960" or similar made ?

I dont't mean the "Scorch" or "Worms" like terrain with many peaks, but I look for a way to generate smooth terain with hills and ditches, smooth enough to let a vehicle drive over it.

Comment: You should try asking at gamedev.stackexchange.com :)

(And also probably looking at sine waves would be a good place to start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Initiate array of random heights

Blur:

foreach height in heights:
  new height = mean of all heights in radius N and center in current height
```

blur will satisfy your condition of smoothing

Answer (score 0):

You want to look for a space-filling-curve, or a spatial index, for example a hilbert curve or a z-curve. It recursivley subdivide the surface into tiles and reduce the 2d problem into a 1d problem but it is basically a reordering of the tiles. You want to look for Nick's spatial index quadtree hilbert-curve blog.